# In App Purchase issue

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am having this trivial issue with InApp Purchase :

I have implemented In App Purchase in my App and when i log in using my sandbox testing account in ITunes store it shows up but if i use my regular  ITunes account, i see a different behaviour and In App purchase are doesn't show up on my Add on Store page

1) Shall i always login to my sandbox testing account while using this app as this app has not been approved yet ?

2) Shall i tick "Cleared for Sale" before submitting to app Store or only after Approval ?

Please provide your valuable inputs

Thanks